# In-app purchase from Japanese app

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, itunes-store, in-app-purchase

So I tried to buy some in-app offers from a app that I downloaded in a different app store region, after putting in my billing information it won't go through. I'm using a US debit/credit card.

Is there anyway to go around the problem like buying a iTunes card then use it for my iTunes account to buy in the in-app offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible. You can buy gift cards from other country iTunes Stores.

One quick search and I found [https://japancodesupply.com/](https://japancodesupply.com/collections/itunes-gift-card), where you can buy Japanese iTunes Gift cards. When you order it takes approximately 1 minute to send you an email with your code.

There are many other websites that offer iTunes Gift cards from other countries. So do a quick search, check the credibility of the website and buy a giftcard.

*I'm not affiliated with japancodesupply.com*

Comment: Is this safe/legitimate?

Comment: Check the customer reviews. Pay with PayPal.. you can always reverse the payment if there is any issue.. and start a case against them..

Comment: I'll try this when I'm free. Thank you for your answer!